Integrating $ \int^p_1 \frac{x 10^x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ by parts
I need to implement an Excel solution to the following equation for an engineering project I'm working on:
$$ \int^p_1 \frac{x 10^x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
where p is a number between 1 and 10.
After using integration by parts, to remove the singularity at 1, I have the following:
$$\int u dv = uv - \int v du $$
$$u = 10^x $$
$$du = ln(10)10^x dx$$
$$v = \sqrt{x^2-1} $$
$$dv = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx $$
$$\int^p_1 \frac{x 10^x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} = 10^x \sqrt{x^2-1}|_1^p - \int^p_1 ln(10)10^x \sqrt{x^2-1} dx $$
However, when I use Excel to approximate the solutions, I am getting a negative answer for the equation generated by integration by parts. I'm approximating the integral in Excel using small values for $dx = 0.001$. It appears to me that in this case, $uv - \int v du $ will always be negative but that the original equation will always be positive.
I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any suggestions.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. What is the exact formula you use in Excel? The issue might be with how Excel formulae work. For example, its default base for logarithms is $10$.

Also, how do you approximate the last integral? You can't just multiply integrand by $dx=0.001$ and use that as an approximation. And simplify $10^x \sqrt{x^2-1}|_1^p =10^p \sqrt{p^2-1}$

KnoxvilleTim, look at this

I used Excel to numerically approximate the integral of $\log(10)10^x\sqrt{x^2-1}$, where "$\log$" denotes the natural logarithm function.  I did not encounter the issue you did.  In fact, the results are correct as validated using WolframAlpha.
You might also try using the following "trick" to handle the singularity.  This "trick" is general and can be applied to a wide range of integrals with singular, but integrable, integrands.
We proceed by rewriting the integral as
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^p \frac{x10^x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx&=\int_1^p \left(\frac{x10^x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\frac{10}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)\,dx+\int_1^p \frac{10}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_1^p \left(\frac{x10^x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\frac{10}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)\,dx +5\log\left(\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2-1}}{p-\sqrt{p^2-1}}\right)
\end{align}$$
Note that the integrand has a removable discontinuity at $1$. Hence one can define its value at $x=1$ to be equal to $0$, which equals its limit from the right.
One can now use Excel to directly numerically approximate this intergal without integrating by parts.
Can you proceed?

Thanks @MarkViola for your response!

@KnoxvilleTim You're welcome.  My pleasure.

@KnoxvilleTim And please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.
